# Example of an equicontinuous family of functions defined on a compact set that is not point-wise bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

As in the title, I am struggling to find a family of functions defined on a compact set that is both equicontinuous and not pointwise bounded.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

What about $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n(x)=n$?

Comment: I should have specified more in the question, but if the space over which the functions are defined on is compact, then this family is pointwise bounded.

Comment: And that's what you asked for, right?! A family of functions which is not pointwise bounded.

Comment: Oh, I see! I read it as $f_n(x) = x$. Wow, can't believe it was so trivial. Thank you.